# Update android notification adding new message to old message

Tags: android, notifications

My app sends notifications but the problem is that if there are some notification pending in the action bar, I want to update the message adding the new message to the old message.

For example, if the message is Hi!, and the device receive another message (Pamela) before the user has opened the old message, I want to show only one notification with the message Hi! Pamela.

My code for send notifications is:

```
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, msg, when);
    String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            FirstActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", msg);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    int notifyID = 1;
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifyID,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, msg, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Is it possible to get the old message of PendingIntent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to concatenate the string, by saving what is already displayed like, before the following is called for the first time:

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("message", msg);   
//save "Hi" , concat "Pamela" update the notification with the same notification id
```

You save the string `msg`, then concatenate the string that you receive in the next notification.  However, to identify, which notifications contain parts of String to be concatenated, is required in this case. Either you can set prefixes to messages or identify by notification id.

Not the ideal way to do it i feel, but can't think of anything else.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question:
> Is it possible to get the old message of PendingIntent?

Comment: you are correct, i just read the question again, editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to retrieve the existing notification from the NotificationManager. You need to keep track of it yourself independently of the notification, and save the unread messages somewhere else (maybe in a SQLite Database or SharedPreferences file).

You will need to determine if the user swipes away the notification, which means you will have to use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` class to create the notification. You can use the `setDeleteIntent` method to supply an Intent to trigger when the notification is swiped away, at which point you delete the old messages from wherever you are storing them so that a new message will show a notification with only the new message.